# Why do I get [] when I'm trying to scrape text from behind a login form?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the message "Click on "Check for new mails" to see new messages. If you want to test this inbox, simply send an email to this address :" from Yopmail. However, I only see "[]" as my result. What am I doing wrong? What's the meaning of "[]"? Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Start the session
session = requests.Session()

# Create the payload
payload = {'login':'1cdsjsdjkdfsnjsdfj42@yopmail.com', 
         }

# Post the payload to the site to log in
s = session.post("http://www.yopmail.com/en/", data=payload)

# Navigate to the next page and scrape the data
s = session.get('http://www.yopmail.com/en/')
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml' )
message = soup.find_all('div', class_='pdet nb')

print(message)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this element exists in the web page?

Comment: have you tried the 'html.parser' instead of lxml ?

Comment: What's the value of `url` ?

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, the meaning of `[]` is that there weren't any `divs` with that particular class found.

And one thing which I think might be the problem is that you use the response from `request.get(url)` and not from `session.get(...)`. I think you might not be logged in if you just use `request.get()`.
The solution would be to use `soup = BeautifulSoup(s.text, 'lxml' )`.

But if that doesn't work the mistake might be that there is actually no `div` with that class.

Answer (score 0):

Try print each variable's result step by step to ensure that data is correctly fetched.

There may be some issues like

Data may not be fetched
No divs on page
No divs with particular class(pdet nb)
Error in login

Try printing soup variable to make sure data is fetched. If not fetched then go one step back and check.